# Render times for PDF page components (parsing, fonts, graphics, etc)

Tags: parsing, pdf, pdf-rendering

I would like to know which operations in PDF page rendering (for a common technical book) take the most time. Is it font rendering? Is it objects parsing? Is it graphics drawing? Or what else?

Comment: It depends on the PDF renderer and the PDF. It can be lots of things (it could also br handling the colour conversion)

Comment: Can you give some background as to what you're doing, to guide people's answers? Do you mean rendering a PDF to the screen, or rendering another format into a PDF (i.e. conversion)?

Comment: @halfer I made some test with technical books, about programming languages. Let's stick to this kind of books, having some layout and some images. I need to know what is the bulk of the operations that is time consuming for screen rendering. I see that one page can be usually rendered in 40 to 100 ms on average with a common notebook (dual core).

Comment: @mark stephens Please can you go on further about the color conversion  issue for images? Or other advice from you.

Comment: Some PDFs are actually tiled CMYK images. This will have a completely different hit to sRGB text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, parsing is a minor, minor cost.  PDF parsing is I/O bound.  In the original version of Acrobat JPEG decoding was one of the largest costs, if you had images that used DCT (since FPUs were not standard).  Antialiased font rendering was expensive at small point sizes, unless Greeking was turned on.  For every high cost item in PDF rendering, there was usually a mechanism to mitigate it (font caching, Greeking, path caching, idle time page rendering, etc).

Comment: your information is precious. So can it be said that font rendering has an important part in rendering time for a common technical book with just some layout and some images?

Comment: Absolutely.  Without JPEGs, in 1993, font rendering would dominate the cost.  Today, the process today would be more likely to be IO bound, but without decent font caching, antialiased font rendering will cost.

Comment: Thanks. Could you roughly guess the time percentage for: font rendering, JPEG decoding, streams uncompressing? (for books with one or two images per page)

Comment: No.  Either task is hugely variable.

Comment: Do you think that creating a new image (memory allocation or object constructor call) for every page could be impacting the rendering time of a big extent?